# Marketing Cloud SQL not executing

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

In Marketing Cloud's Automation Studio, we keep getting an error for SQL we wrote that is supposed to combine the data from 2 separate SHARED data extensions in a child Business Unit. The error message that's prompted is the following

> "An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: The
>   multi-part identifier "ent.France_Master_Permission.Federation_Id"
>   could not be bound."

Below's the whole query:

```
SELECT ent.Country-1_Master_Contacts.TVCM_ID, 
ent.Country-1_Master_Contacts.Contact_Key, 
ent.Country-1_Master_Contacts.Email_Address, 
ent.Country-1_Master_Contacts.First_Name, 
ent.Country-1_Master_Contacts.Last_Name, 
ent.Country-1_Master_Contacts.BU_Code
FROM ent.Country-1_Master_Contacts
INNER JOIN ent.Country-1_Master_Permission
ON ent.Country-1_Master_Permission.Federation_Id 
= ent.Country-1_Master_Contacts.Contact_Key 
AND ent.Country-1_Master_Contacts.TVCM_ID 
= ent.Country-1_Master_Permission.TVCM_ID
WHERE Do_Not_Market_To = 'False' 
AND Unsubscribe_All = 'False' 
AND Email = 'False'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use aliases. Change the query to the following:

```
SELECT mc.TVCM_ID, mc.Contact_Key, mc.Email_Address, mc.First_Name, mc.Last_Name, mc.BU_Code
    FROM ent.Country-1_Master_Contacts mc INNER JOIN ent.Country-1_Master_Permission mp
        ON mp.Federation_Id = mc.Contact_Key 
        AND mp.TVCM_ID = mc.TVCM_ID
    WHERE mp.Do_Not_Market_To = 'False' 
    AND mp.Unsubscribe_All = 'False' 
    AND mp.Email = 'False'
```

It also makes it a lot cleaner and more readable.

I assumed that the attributes in the where clause are from the *Master_Permission* Data Extension. As long as the attributes are unique over the two data extensions; there is no need to specify the alias. But I like to do it for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the field "ent.France_Master_Permission.Federation_Id" in your query. Did you update your SQL ?

When I copy/paste your current SQL in a Query Activity, I have a syntax error. The use of SQL aliases resolves this issue.

I advice you to have a quick look on this page : [SQL Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5)

Comment: Yes, it were aliases in the end. Tnx to both you guys.